# How to find the sum of two selects together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I want to find the sum of these two selects in SQL Server:

```
select count(rez1)*3 as Fit1 from Table_Name where rez1>rez2 

select count(rez1)*1 as Fit2 from Table_Name where rez1=rez2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the `where` clauses to `case` expressions and return integer values, which, in turn, could be summed:

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN rez1 > rez2 THEN 3
                 WHEN rez1 = rez2 THEN 1
            END)
FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
SELECT SUM(T.Fit) AS SumFit
FROM
    (
        select count(rez1)*3 as Fit
        from Table_Name where rez1>rez2

        UNION ALL

        select count(rez1)*1 as Fit
        from Table_Name where rez1=rez2
    ) AS T
```